# Can I run MSXML6 over MSXSL command line tool?

Tags: xslt, command-line, msxml, msxsl

Currently I have installed MSXML3 and MSXML6 (they also can be found in system32 directory).

When I run windows command line tool MSXSL with help option -?:
I get a message stating that
-u version    Use a specific version of MSXML: '2.6', '3.0', '4.0'

Even If I try to use '6.0' - I get an error.
My question is:

Is it possible to use MSXML6 with MSXSL command line tool? If yes, then how?

Comment: MSDN downloads also has the C++ sources of the command line tool, however the version I have found there at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21714 indeed only supports the versions of MSXML up to 4.0. I guess a C++ programmer could easily extend the code to also allow using MSXML 6. It is also possible to write some lines of JScript or VBScript to be executed by Windows Script Host to call MSXML.

Comment: Thanks, I've used the WSH option. If you would post this as an answer I would accept it, because MSXSL indeed support only MSXML up to version 4 which is already deprecated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [successor of msxsl.exe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058247/successor-of-msxsl-exe)