# XSLT Reports and Internet Explorer

Tags: xslt

with IE at its EOL and allowing file access from files in Chrome is not a viable option for us, what is the future of XSLT reports?

I am fairly new to this, and have just been "thrown" into finding a solution. Everything I'm finding online is years old, it's strange that no one is talking about this since "death" of IE.

our data is in XML format, using XSL templates to display formatted reports to browser via ScriptX (smsx.cab) (with page breaks, headers, etc). The user then "prints to PDF"

I am hoping to see what other organizations are doing to ensure existing XSLT reports continue to work. Converting to something else? Making them work with other, currently supported, browsers?

thank you, all and any tips, links and comments much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "XSLT reports". What's your pipeline? Where do you take your input from? Where do you want your output?

Comment: yes, thank you! i will update the quesion

Comment: Is your input data local in the user's machine? Transformations straight in the browser are pretty much not available anymore because of the browser's security constraints. You could use a script (powershell, batch) to process the input and then let the user open the resulting file in the required application.

Comment: currently, we have an application that generates the XML file and saves them locally, with the appropriate XSL stylesheets, if you could please throw some names of the scripts i need to google for, to help me figure out where to start with changing how the input is to be processed.

Comment: In which language is the application that produces the XML files? Could this application apply the XSLT transforms directly?

Comment: it's in .NET. i think i found what i need, which is XSLTransform. that said, does this mean we will not be able to open reports directly from folder ever again? we would always need an "Application" to call and open reports? Before IE getting removed, i was able to click on any XML file, and see it formatted, directly from my windows explorer folder, in IE.

Comment: I think the use case for what you describe is easily avoidable. Your application could easily output the raw XML and the formated version as two separate files and the user would be then be able to use one or the other without further transformations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try executing your XSLT transformations using a local script.
Take note that these solutions only support XSLT 1.0.

**MSXML**
[successor of msxsl.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058247/successor-of-msxsl-exe)

**PowerShell**
[Applying XSL to XML with PowerShell : Exception calling "Transform"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37024568/applying-xsl-to-xml-with-powershell-exception-calling-transform)

If you want to use XSLT 2.0+
You can use **Saxon** and call the jar file from a batch file.
https://www.saxonica.com/

Comment: ! thank yoU!! just did a quick test using XMLTransform, which basically generates a formatted HTML files using the XML and the stylesheet, and it is PERFECT! thank yoU!